# Extracting the Hamiltonian from given canonical equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation, hamilton-equations

Say I have a physical system that gives me directly a set of equations in terms of the generalised coordinates ($q_{i}$) and generalised momenta ($p_{i}$) as

$$\frac{dq_{i}}{dt}=\dot{q_{i}}=f_{1}(\vec{q},\vec{p},t),$$
$$\frac{dp_{i}}{dt}=\dot{p_{i}}=f_{2}(\vec{q},\vec{p},t),$$

with index $i=1, \cdots, n$, where $\vec{q}=(q_{1}, \cdots, q_{n})$, $\vec{p}=(p_{1}, \cdots, p_{n})$ and $n$ is the degrees of freedom (number of independent variables). The functions $f_{1}$ and $f_{2}$ are known.

I would like to use these as my canonical equations to extract a Hamiltonian $H=H(\vec{q},\vec{p},t)$ that would satisfy them.

Classically we are given $H$ first and then we take the partial derivates in $p$ and $q$ to get these canonical equations; namely

$$\dot{q_{i}}=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_{i}}$$
$$\dot{p_{i}}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_{i}}$$

Now I am concerned with the opposite direction.

I suspect the answer will not be unique. Nevertheless, the fact that $\partial H/\partial t=d H/dt$ makes attempts to integrate rather futile. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the vector $(\partial H/\partial q_1,\dots,\partial H/\partial q_n,\partial H/\partial p_1,\dots,\partial H/\partial p_n)$,
you can follow the usual step-by-step procedure for finding a potential for a vector field (or showing that there is none), which is illustrated for example [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1182717/1242) in a case with three variables.

Comment: But I think there is a problem with the approach you mention when we use it here, in the context of generalised momenta ($p_{i}$) and generalised coordinates ($q_{i}$), which I think was not present in the typical example of potential calculation you cited. Specifically, here we may have $p_{i}=p_{i}(q_{1}, \cdots, q_{n}, \dot{q_{1}}, \cdots, \dot{q_{n}}, t)$ (function of $q_{i}$ and its derivates), thus $p_{i}$ might not be explicitly independent from $q_{i}$. So, when we try to remove integration contants step by step as in your example for potential, there may be a complication. Any ideas?

Comment: No, $q_i$ and $p_i$ are considered as **independent** variables in Hamiltonian mechanics! Otherwise, how could you even compute $\partial H/\partial p_i$, varying one $p_i$ while keeping all the $q_k$ constant?

Comment: $q_{i}$ is independent from $p_{i}$, but the converse is not necessarily true (as per the definition of generalised momenta, which comes from $\partial L(\vec{q},\vec{\dot{q}},t)/\partial \dot{q_{i}}$)

Comment: In Hamiltonian mechanics you pick a function $H(q,p,t)$ which defines the dynamics on your phase space via $\dot q_i = \partial H/\partial p_i$ and $\dot p_i = -\partial H/\partial q_i$, where the partial derivatives are nothing but standard partial derivatives, with the variables considered as completely independent from one another, for the purposes of taking derivatives.

Comment: Now of course these ODEs determine a time evolution of a point $(q(t),p(t))$, but then (in general) each coordinate $q_i$ for that point is coupled to all the other $q_i$ (so in that sense even the $q_i$ are *not* independent of each other!) and also coupled to all the $p_i$, and similarly each $p_i$ is (in general) coupled to all the other variables. If $H$ happens to have some particular form, then you might get for example $\dot q_i = p_i$, but that's irrelevant for your question. The time evolution is not involved when computing the partial derivatives of $H$.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are correct. My mistake. Thanks for your answer!