# Potential from a vector field, and why the naive approach doesn't seem to work?

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics

Given a field $\vec{F} = <F_x,F_y,F_z>$;
If a potential can be defined at any point, then the field is necessarily conservative and we can use *any* path to find the potential. I'll consider moving along the axes. Thus, from an arbitrary starting point $(0,0,0)$, integrating first along the x-axis (where $y$, $z$ are constants), then along the y-axis, then the z-axis, should give the potential associated with an arbitrary point $(x,y,z)$.

I.e., $-U = \int_0^x F_xdx + \int_0^y F_ydy + \int_0^z F_zdz$
which is of course, $U(x,y,z) = -\int{\vec{F}\cdot <dx,dy,dz>}$

Now, I know that this doesn't work (eg given below), and I also know how to solve the question correctly from Mark Viola's answer to another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182684/finding-potential-function-for-a-vector-field) on here. I also understand why that solution works. But why doesn't this?

*example*

$\vec{F} = <4xy, 2x^2>$, thus $U = -\int_{(0,0)}^{(x,0)}4xydx + -\int_{(x,0)}^{(x,y)}2x^2dy =-\int_0^{(x,y)} \vec{F}\cdot <dx,dy>$
 $U = -\int_0^x 4xydx + -\int_0^y 2x^dy = -2x^2y + -2x^2y + C = -4x^2y + C$

but if you verify using $\vec{F} = -\nabla\cdot U$, we don't get the original $\vec{F}$ back.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your method entails---perhaps add some additional steps for your example?, which will make it easier to pinpoint the issue?

Comment: Well, if the field is conservative, then I can use any arbitrary path from $(0,0,0)$  to $(x,y,z)$. I'll let my path be one that goes from $(0,0,0)$ to $(x,0,0)$, then to $(x,y,0)$, and finally to $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Provided the field is conservative, that *will* produce a potential. In any case, adding your work for your example to the question statement will make it easier to identify the particular issue.

Comment: $y=0$ along the path from $(0,0)$ to $(x,0)$, so $F_x=4xy=0$.

Comment: Ow, that's an embarrassingly trivial mistake on my part. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because @Goncalo found a trivial mistake.